# Ng2 DateTime Picker calender / manually is not accessible using angular javascript

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, datetimepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I have made the customized selection of date start Date & Start Time . For the Start Date , im using the ng2 datetime picker library & for the start time , using the two placeholders with the dropdown for selection of hours and minutes. And for the Everyday frequency only , i have give the customization of From Date-Time & To Date-Time selection. That From Date-Time & To Date-Time is set using the Start Date & Start-Time.

But, When I give the input of start Date & Start Time , then for Everyday frequency only , the dropdown is there , in that fromDate-time & toDate-Time date-time picker is there. When I give the input of start Date & Start Time, then fromDate-time &toDate-TIme is set & we can manually also select date & time.

But when I again change the start Date or Start Time , then the fromDate-Time & toDate-Time date-time picker is not showing calender & time or not giving the access for manual change of date & time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L31wz.png) , My UI preview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxIi9.png) , Problem im facing for that

```
<HTML Code>

  <div class="col-md-3 ">
          <label extraFun="Task_Add_Start_Date" for="startDate">Start Date
            <span style="color:red;">*</span>:</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="startdateMoment" (ngModelChange)="updateDateTimeRange()" [disabled]="true" [disabled]="isViewOnly == 1 || viewReport || (!addBtnView && !viewReport)"
            class="form-control" ng2-datetime-picker [date-format]="'DD-MM-YYYY'" date-only="true"
            [close-on-select]="false" [show-close-layer]="true" year="2018" month="12" day="31"
            style="background-color: white;" [disabled]="true"
            [style.background-color]="(disableStartDateInput == true || taskView == true || IsOnlyStatusView == true) ? '#eeeeee' : '#fff'"
            placeholder="Start Date" />
            {{startdateMoment | json}}
        </div>

        <!--[disabled] ="TaskstartDate"--->
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
          <label for="ex3">Start Time<span style="color:red">*</span>:</label>
          <div class="input-group" style="display:flex;">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            </div>
            <ng-select [items]="hours" [disabled]="isViewOnly == 1 || viewReport || (!addBtnView && !viewReport)"
              [clearable]="false" class="pull-left" [(ngModel)]="strtTime" style="display:flex;"
              style="width:40%;height:34px" (ngModelChange)="updateDateTimeRange()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <!-- <option value="HH" selected hidden disabled>HH</option>
                          <option *ngFor="let hour of hours" style="width:16%;" class="form-control" value="{{hour}}" required>
                            {{hour}}</option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -->
            </ng-select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <ng-select [items]="mintunes" [disabled]="isViewOnly == 1 || viewReport || (!addBtnView && !viewReport)"
              [clearable]="false" class="pull-left" [(ngModel)]="strtTimeMins" style="width:40%;height:34px"
              (ngModelChange)="updateDateTimeRange()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <!-- <option value="MM" name="mins" selected hidden disabled>MM</option>
                          <option *ngFor="let mins of mintunes" name="mins" class="form-control" style="width:16%;"
                            value="{{mins}}" required>{{mins}}</option>&nbsp;&nbsp; -->
            </ng-select>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="ShowStartTimeHoursError" style="color:red">Start Time Should be Same or Greater than
            Current Time
          </div>
          <!--   row end-->
        </div>
 <ng-container *ngIf="getfrequencyid === 2">
        <div class="col-md-12 top10">
          <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="enableDateTime">
              Date-Time Input
            </label>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isDateTimeEnble"
              (change)="updateTime($event.target.checked)" [disabled]="!checkboxEnabled && isEdit">
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isDateTimeEnble">
            <div class="col-md-3 marginBottom">
              <label for="startDate">From Date-Time:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend"></div>
                <input [(ngModel)]="fromDateTime" class="form-control" ng2-datetime-picker date-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"
                  [close-on-select]="false" [show-close-layer]="true" year="2018" month="12" day="31"
                  style="background-color: white; border-radius: 4px;" placeholder="From Time" />
                  {{fromDateTime | json}}
                <div><button id="from-tooltip" class="btn-group" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="From Date-Time derived from selected start date and time. Accordingly, it calculates date and time which gives the timeframe of 24 hours."
                    data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                  </button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div *ngIf="isDateTimeEnble">
            <div class="col-md-3 marginBottom">
              <label for="endDate">To Date-Time:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                </div>
                <input [(ngModel)]="toDateTime" class="form-control" ng2-datetime-picker date-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"
                  [close-on-select]="false" [show-close-layer]="true" year="2018" month="12" day="31"
                  style="background-color: white; border-radius: 4px;" placeholder="To Time" />
                  {{toDateTime | json}}
                <div><button id="from-tooltip" class="btn-group" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="To Date-Time derived from selected start date and time. Accordingly, it calculates date and time which gives the timeframe of 24 hours."
                    data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                  </button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
```

```
<TS Code>

isDateTimeEnble: boolean = true;
  isEnabled: boolean = false;

today = new Date();
  startdateObj: any;
  startdateMoment: any;
  enddateObj: any;
  hours = ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09",
    "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"];
  mintunes = [...this.hours,
    "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37",
    "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51",
    "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"]
  getTimeZ() {
    debugger;
    this.strtTime = 'HH';
    this.strtTimeMins = 'MM'; 

    this.fromHrsTime = 'HH';
    this.fromMinsTime = 'MM';
    this.toHrsTime = 'HH';
    this.toMinsTime = 'MM';
    
   this.startdateMoment = moment().startOf('day');
    this.startdateObj = this.today.getDate().toString();
    let date = new Date();
    let hours: any;
    let mins: any;
    if (date.getHours() < 10) {
      hours = '0' + date.getHours().toString();
    } else {
      hours = date.getHours().toString();
    }
    if (date.getMinutes() < 10) {
      mins = '0' + date.getMinutes().toString();
    } else {
      mins = date.getMinutes().toString();
    }

    this.strtTime = "00";
    this.strtTimeMins = "00";

    this.fromHrsTime = "00";
    this.fromMinsTime = "00";
    this.toHrsTime = "00";
    this.toMinsTime = "00";

    this.strthrs = "00";
    this.strtmins = "00";

    this.enddateObj = (this.today.getDate()).toString();
    return this.startdateObj, this.enddateObj;
  }
updateDateTimeRange() {
    const startDateTime = moment(this.startdateMoment + ' ' + this.strtTime + ':' + this.strtTimeMins, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
    this.fromDateTime = moment(startDateTime).subtract(1, 'days');
    const toDateTime = moment(startDateTime); 
    this.toDateTime = moment(toDateTime);
    console.log('fromDate', this.fromDateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
    console.log('toDate', this.toDateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));

  }

degugger;
  updateTime(event: any) {
    this.isDateTimeEnble == this.isEnabled;
  if (this.isDateTimeEnble == this.isEnabled) {
    this.isUnchecked = false;
    return;
  }
  else {
    this.isUnchecked = true;
    return;
  }
}
```

I have tried this but im getting this error as [When I change the start Time or start Date , then  when I select the from date-time  or To date-time , then the calender is not give the access for the manual change & this error is appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Yr6.png)
. I think the problem is with the date type ,Im using the moment type, its correct but still im not getting it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: pls don't tag angularJS. This is angular, not the same